# Need help with ubuntu cloud

Tags: cloud

I am looking to start a cloud storage service and i was looking at ubuntu to do that, but i need to know how the public and or clients can signup and use my cloud servers. Can anyone tell me where to go or what is the best to use for this?

thanks

Comment: It's a little unclear what you are asking for. Are you looking to implement an authentication mechanism for your service? What have your looked at/considered/tried already?

Comment: i am trying to become a cloud storage provider and i am not sure what the best way to do that and how I can have my clients connect to it

Comment: No. It's a really interesting question. But, any additional details that you could provide would help us answer your question and, hopefully, point you in the right direction. Please add any additional info in your original question. It sounds like you have picked a cloud platform and are looking for authentication mechanisms. Is that correct? What have you chosen?

Comment: i havnt choose any yet i was thinking of using openstack i am trying to do somthing like this site http://www.justcloud.com/ is that possiable with openstack